# what does the red circle with a white x in it on an icon in the tweaks sidebar

Tags: settings, tweak-tool

[image]

As may be seen above, I suddenly have a red circle with a white "x" in it superimposed on my Fonts and Launcher icons in the sidebar of my tweaks setting panel. Looks like it's trying to warn me about something, but everything seems to work ok. Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Does it go away if you change the icon theme?

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes! But when I went back to the old icon theme it was no longer there either. Strange but all's well that ends well!

Answer (score 0):

This is your icon themes representation of a "missing icon". The theme does not provide the icons required for those items in the sidebar, so it displays that instead.

As you have found from the comments under your question, changing to an icon theme that provides those icons fixes the issue.